# CylindricalDecomposition with symbolic variables

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, inequalities

`CylindricalDecomposition` is a powerful function that can (for instance) compute the limits for each variable in integrals over a region.  Suppose the region is:

```
x^2 + 2 y^2 + z^2 < 1
```

Then

`CylindricalDecomposition[x^2 + 2 y^2 + z^2 < 1, {x, y, z}]` yields:

$$-1<x<1\land
   -\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{2}}<y<\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{2}}\land
   -\sqrt{-x^2-2 y^2+1}<z<\sqrt{-x^2-2 y^2+1}$$

***Question***:  Why won't this function work with *symbols*?

```
Clear[a, b, c];
CylindricalDecomposition[x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 + z^2/c^2 < 1, 
    {x, y, z}]
```

(* error message *)

How can I overcome this limitation?

And why won't it work for this?

`CylindricalDecomposition[(x - y)^2 + y^2 + (z - .5 x)^2 < 1,{x,y,z}]`?

@MarcoB astutely points out that the function needs infinite precision.  Hence this last question is solved by:

`CylindricalDecomposition[(x-y)^2 + y^2 + (z - x/2)^2 < 1,{x,y,z}]`

Comment: For the last example, CylindricalDecomposition requires exact, infinite‐precision input, so it will work if you convert 0.5 to 1/2 (see Possible issues in its docs). In your previous example, I am not sure that Assuming is doing anything, since CylindricalDecomposition does not take an Assumptions option.

Comment: @MarcoB:  Perfect.  Thanks.  (I'll make a note in the OP as this is essentially solved.)

Comment: `With[{d=SinIntegral@{1,2,3}},CylindricalDecomposition[#.#&[{x,y,z}/d]<1,{x,y,z}]/.Thread[d->{a,b,c}]]` or `Refine[Reduce[x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2+z^2/c^2<1,{x,y,z}],Positive@{a,b,c}]`

Comment: @chyanog:  Very interesting and helpful but how would we know to use a SinIntegral here?  And what if our function is not so simple that the SinIntegral is appropriate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give CylindricalDecompositon all variables and parameters to work with. But it depends on order. It regards the first given as parameters and the last as variables.

```
Simplify@CylindricalDecomposition[
  x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 + z^2/c^2 < 1, {a, b, c, x, y, z}]

(*   Sqrt[b^2 (1 - x^2/a^2)] + y > 0 && y < Sqrt[b^2 (1 - x^2/a^2)] && 
 Sqrt[c^2 (1 - x^2/a^2 - y^2/b^2)] + z > 0 && 
 z < Sqrt[c^2 (1 - x^2/a^2 - y^2/b^2)] && a != 0 && b != 0 && 
 c != 0 && ((a > 0 && a > x && a + x > 0) || (a < 0 && a < x && 
     a + x < 0))   *)

Simplify@CylindricalDecomposition[
  x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 + z^2/c^2 < 1, {x, y, z, a, b, c}]

(*   (a + x < 0 || a > x || x <= 0) && (a < x || a + x > 0 || 
   x > 0) && (b + Sqrt[(a^2 y^2)/(a^2 - x^2)] < 0 || 
   b > Sqrt[(a^2 y^2)/(
    a^2 - x^2)]) && (c + Sqrt[(
     a^2 b^2 z^2)/(-b^2 x^2 + a^2 (b^2 - y^2))] < 0 || 
   c > Sqrt[(a^2 b^2 z^2)/(-b^2 x^2 + a^2 (b^2 - y^2))])   *)
```

Comment: Ahah!  That's the trick.  Thanks so much.  ($\checkmark$)